# Mix two lists python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a function to mix two lists in python, or I rather say put the element of list2 into list1. It is required that in the output list, no more than two elements next two each other have the same value

For example:

```
list1 = [1,1,1,1,1]
list2 = [2,2,2,2,2]
output = [1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2]
```

Wrong output example:

```
# There are more than two '1' standing next two each other
output = [1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2]
```

Here is my solution:

```
def guyGenerator(toughGuy,softGuy):
    i = 0
    while len(softGuy) > 0:
        temp = softGuy[:1]
        while i < len(toughGuy) - 1:
            if toughGuy[i] == toughGuy[i + 1] == 2:
                toughGuy.insert(random.randint(i, i + 1), temp[0])
            i = i + 1
        softGuy = softGuy[1:]
    return toughGuy
```

The issue is getting the output with more than two of the same elements standing next two each other or the length of the output list is longer than combine length of two lists

For example one of my output

```
[2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

**Edit 1**

Clodion asked me so I put this up here

The results can be random, as long as they satisfy the requirement in the question. The order of the elements does not matter as long as no more than two elements standing next to each other have the same value

**Edit 2**

I am trying to mess around by create a iterable class, using Clodion solution. Here is the new code:

```
import random

class GuyGenerator:
    def __init__(self,toughGuyList,softGuyList):
        self.toughGuyList = toughGuyList
        self.softGuyList = softGuyList
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        listSum = self.toughGuyList + self.softGuyList
        while True:
            res = random.sample(listSum,len(listSum))
            if not any([res[i-2]==res[i-1]==res[i] for i in range(len(listSum))]):
                break
        return res

toughGuy = ['tough','tough','tough','tough','tough','tough','tough','tough']
softGuy = ['soft','soft','soft','soft','soft','soft','soft','soft']
for guy in GuyGenerator(toughGuy,softGuy):
    print(guy)
```

The result turned out quite well, except for the code executing unlimited and I have to use KeyboardInterrupt to stop the code. What am I doing wrong in this case ? I would be grateful with a thorough explain since I am a newbie in Python and Iterator

**Edit 3**

Solved the iterator problem, easier than I think. It turned out that what returned in the **iter** is what the class return when calling in the for-loop

Solution:

```
def __iter__(self):    
    listSum = self.listRandom1 + self.listRandom2
    while True:
        self.res = random.sample(listSum,len(listSum))
        if not any([self.res[i-2]==self.res[i-1]==self.res[i] for i in range(len(listSum))]):
            break
    return iter(self.res)
```

Comment: What happens if the `list`s are such that there's no way to arrange them like this (e.g. `list1=[1,1,1]; list2=[1,1,1]`)? Does each `list` always contain a single number?

Comment: @Tuan Dinh: Can you said if you want random result or not please? Thanks in advance. And edit your question to write it?

Comment: @Clodion: yes, the result can be random, as long as they satisfy the requirement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could implement a greedy algorithm which tries to yield the most common item
as frequently as possible (i.e. up to twice), and then yield the next most common item
when necessary.

This has two advantages over search by random shuffle:

- The greedy algorithm is much faster as the length of `items` increases:

  ```
  In [223]: %timeit list(intermix([1]*10+[2]*5))
  10000 loops, best of 3: 39.8 µs per loop

  In [222]: %timeit intermix_random([1]*10+[2]*5)
  100 loops, best of 3: 6.85 ms per loop
  ```
- It can identify when there is no solution, whereas a random shuffle search
  loops forever if visited shuffles are not cached.

---

```
import collections
def intermix(items, nconsecutive=2):
    counter = collections.Counter(items)
    # sort from most common to least common
    items = sorted(items, key=counter.get, reverse=True)
    N = len(items)
    count = 0
    # remember the last two values
    last = []
    for i in range(N):
        val = items[i]
        if len(last) < nconsecutive:
            if last and val == last[-1]:
                last.append(val)
            else:
                last = [val]
            counter[val] -= 1
            yield val
        else:
            # last is full; find a different value
            for j in range(i, N):
                if items[j] != last[-1]:
                    items[i], items[j] = items[j], items[i]
                    val = items[i]
                    last = [val]
                    counter[val] -= 1
                    # as items are yielded, the meaning of "most common" can change.
                    items[i+1:] = sorted(items[i+1:], key=counter.get, reverse=True)
                    yield val
                    break
            else:
                raise ValueError('No solution possible')
```

---

```
In [184]: list(intermix([1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]))
Out[184]: [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]

In [185]: list(intermix([1,0,1,1,2,1,0,1,1,1,2]))
Out[185]: [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0]

In [186]: list(intermix([1,0,1,1,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]))
Out[186]: [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]

In [187]: list(intermix([1,0,1,1,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]))
ValueError: No solution possible

In [188]: list(intermix([1,0,1,1,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2], nconsecutive=3))
Out[188]: [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Well, result should be random⋅… No?

Comment: @Clodion - no, I see no requirement for a random result. I don't know where you're getting that.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: please look at my answer below my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shuffle` from `random`:

```
list1=[1,1,1,1,1]
list2=[2,2,2,2,2]
import random
lst = list1+list2
print(lst)
while True:
    random.shuffle(lst)
    if not any([lst[i-2]==lst[i-1]==lst[i]for i in range(len(lst))]):
        break
print(lst)
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
```

Explanation: I add the two list and `suffle` it. Then I repeat `shuffle` until there's not 3 same consecutive numbers. As comment point out, it may take a long time but it's easy to make a limit of iterations.
Trying to explain why your code don't work:

```
def guyGenerator(toughGuy,softGuy):
    import random
    i = 0
    while len(softGuy) > 0:
        temp = softGuy[:1]
        while i < len(toughGuy)- 1:
            if toughGuy[i] == toughGuy[i + 1] == 2:
                # you insert temp[0]: it can be inserted before i
                # for lst = [0, 1, 2, 3]
                # lst.insert(0, "X") result in ["X", 0, 1, 2, 3]
                # But then, the next time, you'll test exactly the
                # same thing: because you increment i and have move all
                # the items of toughGuy one char to the right
                # and that, without reducing softGuy len.
                toughGuy.insert(random.randint(i, i + 1), temp[0])
            i = i + 1
        softGuy = softGuy[1:]
    return toughGuy

print(guyGenerator([2,2,2,2,2], [1,1,1,1,1]))
```

Well? I'm clear?

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> lst.insert(0, "X")
>>> lst
['X', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> lst.insert(1, "X")
>>> lst
[1, 'X', 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

If `randint` give `i`, then "X" is inserted before the items.
You increment i and you so i locate exactly the same element:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> lst.insert(0, "X")
>>> lst
['X', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> lst.insert(1, "X")
>>> lst
['X', 'X', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

That's the problem, because you're still in the same loop!!!
So you can insert more than one temp[0] before reducing softGuy by one element. Yes?
Any suggestion would be welcome!

Comment: Please, why this "-1"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont know why "-1", but I am testing your solution 
But can you tell what I am doing wrong in my solution ?

Comment: A solution based on randomness and which could theoretically run for hours bothers me, this is laziness, this is not a nice way to code.

Comment: @Delgan: You are right. But I don't have other solution. No?

Comment: Downvote from me as well for using [Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort). I'm sure I don't have to explain why this solution is really, really bad.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Yes, but have you another solution? It certainly have another solution, but I don't find it… And it's easy to limit iteration number if we want! No?

Comment: @unutbu's answer is excellent. I can hardly believe that you're trying to defend a Bogosort as a practical, useful algorithm.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Of course not! You're wrong! Result have to be random! Unutbu's did not respond to the question! And I just trying to respond at the question!

Comment: I saw no requirement of a random result, nor any mention of randomness. @ubutnu not only responded to the question, he gave a complete answer filled with excellent advice. You should at least edit your answer to make it perfectly clear what sort of algorithm you're using.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Tuan Dinh write: `output=[1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2]` as example of what he want. Then, he use `toughGuy.insert(random.randint(i,i+1),temp[0])`. For me he want random. And Unutbu did not respond to my comment!

Comment: @Clodion I'd say he doesn't care of the output, as long as there are no more than two of the same element next to each other. Sure random is fine, but it doesn't have to be random.

Comment: can you guys tell me where I am wrong at in my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take an approach inspired by the bubble sort algorithm.  This would consist in swapping numbers to break 3-value streaks until no more swaps are needed.  In other words for every `a,a,a,b` swap `b` with the preceding `a` to make it `a,a,b,a`.

```
list1 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
list2 = [2,2,2,2,2]

output   = list1+list2
swapping = True
while swapping:
    swapping = False
    for i in range(3,len(output)):
         if output[i] != output[i-1] and output[i-3:i-1] == output[i-2:i]:
             swapping = True
             output[i-1:i+1] = output[i-1:i+1][::-1] 

print(output)
[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```